# Receiving incomplete HTTP request

Tags: http

I have an Arduino project that needs to receive data from ThingSpeak. [This](https://thingspeak.com/channels/344468/fields/3/last) is the data that I'm supposed to get.

When the data is "true" it must turn the LED on. I tried this code in hope of getting "true".

```
void loop() { 
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Receiving Trigger Data...");
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("Connected to server");
    client.println("GET /channels/344468/fields/3/last?key=XXXXXXX HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: api.thingspeak.com");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
}
while (client.available()) {
  reply = client.read();
  content.concat(reply);
}
delay(3000);
Serial.println(content);
if(content.indexOf("Content-Length: 4") > 0) {
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
}
```

The Serial Monitor gives this reply. I don't see the word "true" being returned at all and I don't also see the content length. I tried putting delays but still I don't receive the "true" or even just the content length. Please help.

[image]

Comment: available() is non blocking. network is not so fast. at the first gap you stop reading

Comment: I think you can to use `client.connected()` to determine whether there is still data coming in (since you are sending the Connection: close header).

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed available() to connected() and it worked properly now.